# Selection of two number from 1 to n with difference greater than m.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A bag contains n tickets marked 1 to n if two tickets are drawn then find the probability that difference on the numbers exceeds m where m < n - 1.

Well, the total number events is quite easy to find which is **C(n,2)** but I am having difficulties finding the favourable outcomes.

Answer (score 1):

The number of ways of selecting two tickets with difference greater than $m$ is the number of ways of arranging two green and $n - 2$ blue balls so that there are at least $m$ blue balls between the pair of green balls.

Suppose we have $n$ blue balls.  Set aside $m$ of them for later use.  That leaves us with $n - m$ blue balls.  Select two of them.  Paint the selected balls green.  Now put the $m$ blue balls we set aside to the immediate right of the leftmost green ball.  Now number the balls from left to right.  The numbers on the two green balls have difference greater than $m$.  Therefore, the number of favorable cases is 
$$\binom{n - m}{2}$$
Hence, the probability that the numbers on the two tickets will differ by more than $m$ is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{n - m}{2}}{\dbinom{n}{2}}$$

To illustrate the process, suppose $n = 12$ and $m = 5$.  Set aside five blue balls, leaving us with seven blue balls.

[image: blue_balls]

We now choose two of these seven blue balls to paint green.  For instance, if we pick the third and fifth balls, we obtain the arrangement shown below.

[image: blue_and_green_balls]

To ensure that there are at least five blue balls between the two green balls, we now insert the five blue balls we set aside to the immediate right of the first green ball.

[image: blue_and_green_balls_with_inserted_blue_balls]

We now number the balls from left to right.  The numbers on the green balls will differ by more than five.  In this case, the numbers on the green balls are $3$ and $10$.  Notice that $10 - 3 = 7 > 5$.  Even if we had picked adjacent balls, the difference of the numbers on the green balls (our tickets) would differ by $6 > 5$.